# Printing Non Repeating Characters first

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL and I am trying to write a procedure which would print the non repeating characters of an input string first and Repeating characters of the string in the last. For example if the input string is "Array" then the output should be "yArra".

I wrote a part of it for searching the no. of occurrences of a repeating character, but don't know how exactly should it be printed at the first place.

I wrote an algorithm on this on how can this be made to work but finding difficult to code

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Show us your algorithm at least!

Comment: @user7415151  why have you deleted the previous post ???

Comment: @ShaiRado It was trying to edit the answer and inadvertently clicked delete :( my bad luck , network went down and i couldn't undelete it. Is there a way to get my post back ? :-(

Comment: Not sure how, you ca re-post

Comment: Will re-post now. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to write a procedure which would print the non repeating
>   characters of an input string first and Repeating characters of the
>   string in the last.

You can do this using a pure `PLSQL` code as below:

```
create or replace procedure prnt_letter(strng varchar2) as

  var  varchar2(1);
  var1 varchar2(1000) := '';
  var2 varchar2(1);
  var3 varchar2(1000) := '';

  strn_len number;

begin

  dbms_output.put_line('Input String --> ' || strng);

  strn_len := length(strng);

  var := substr(strng, 1, 1);

  for i in 1 .. strn_len loop

    if (var = substr(strng, i, 1)) then
      var2 := substr(strng, i, 1);
      var3 := var3 || var2;
      var  := substr(strng, i, 1);
    else
      var1 := var1 || substr(strng, i, 1);
      var  := substr(strng, i, 1);
    end if;

  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('Output String --> '||var1 || var3);

end;
```

**EDIT:** 
Here is my revised solution both in `PLSQL` and `SQL`. This works for any string.

PLSQL:

```
create or replace procedure prnt_letter(strng varchar2) as

  var1 varchar2(1000) := '';
  strn_len number;

begin

  dbms_output.put_line('Input String --> ' || strng);

  strn_len := length(strng);

   SELECT reverse (LISTAGG (vertical, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1 DESC)) 
   into var1
    FROM (    
            SELECT SUBSTR (strng, LEVEL, 1) Vertical
            FROM DUAL
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= strn_len            
         ) ;

  dbms_output.put_line('Output String --> '||var1 );

end;
```

Output:

```
SQL> execute prnt_letter('rajjjjkkmmaaljjjl');
Input String --> rajjjjkkmmaaljjjl
Output String --> rmmllkkjjjjjjjaaa

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> execute prnt_letter('bubble');
Input String --> bubble
Output String --> ulebbb

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

SQL:
-- Logic used:

- 1) The input string is first arranged vertically in separate rows and
  then ordered
- 2) Using `LISTAGG`, the result was assembled as a single ordered string
- 3) Using `REVERSE` the non-repeating string is brought to the starting
  of the string.

  `SELECT reverse (LISTAGG (vertical, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1 DESC)) col1
            FROM (    SELECT SUBSTR ('rajjjjkkmmaaljjjl', LEVEL, 1) Vertical
                        FROM DUAL
                  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH ('rajjjjkkmmaaljjjl')

                  )`

Comment: No, We should not take that condition XING. OP should be uleBbb. if there are three b's/B's all of them should be considered as repeating characters

Comment: @user7415151. You must think first what you want. Because looking at your example what i provided is correct `input string is "Array" then the output should be "yArra". ` So here as well the output should be `yAarr`

Comment: @user7415151. Check my revised solution which works as per your requirement. I hope you won't change your requirement now.

Comment: Now you're talking! Listagg master

Comment: Hope you understood why i used listagg & reverse

Comment: @XING, nope, I'm no match for you... you could explain it to us if you were kind. I also suspect OP was not clear with here requirement.

Comment: @J.Chomel. I agree with you. OP changes his requirement and that make the solution invalid. Well coming to usage of LISTAGG & Reverse see my comments in the post.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! This was a great learning experience and apologies for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1):

Try and use the REGEXP_COUNT function for the same. You can first provide a filter where this result >1 to find repeating characters and then concatenate them with the ones whose count = 1.

[Check how to use regexp_count](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_count.php)

Comment: This is not a answer. It can be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution can be acheived by just using pure SQL rather than using PLSQL. Hope below snippet helps.

```
SELECT a.COL
  ||REPLACE('&Enter_text',a.col,'') output
FROM
  (SELECT regexp_count('&Enter_text',SUBSTR('&Enter_text',level,1)) col1,
    SUBSTR('&Enter_text',level,1) col
  FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY level <=LENGTH('&Enter_text')
  )a
WHERE a.col1 = 1;
```

Comment: Because there can be three combinations for that

Comment: That's not what I understood from OP... I thought it had to keep characters orders, and be case sensitive. Maybe I went a little to far in the interpretation of the changing requirement ;) Great solution.

Answer (score 1):

That's fun, so I came out with something easily understandable using associative arrays as Hashmap; there's something subtle also with the non-case-sensitiveness:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f(p_str in varchar2)
  RETURN varchar2
AS
  TYPE map_v IS TABLE OF integer INDEX BY varchar2(1);
  l_dup map_v;
  i PLS_INTEGER;
  l_c varchar2(1);
  l_tc varchar2(1);
  l_nb_occurrences integer := NULL;
  l_out_sngl varchar2(2000) := '';
  l_out_dupl varchar2(2000) := '';
BEGIN
--  l_dup('a'):=0;
--  l_dup('b'):=0;

-- first loop to count occurrences
  i:=1;
  LOOP
    l_c := lower(substr(p_str, i, 1));   
    begin
      l_nb_occurrences := l_dup(l_c);
      l_dup(l_c) := l_nb_occurrences + 1;
      dbms_output.put_line(l_c||':incr:'||i);

    exception 
      when no_data_found then
        l_dup(l_c) := 1;
        dbms_output.put_line(l_c||':pushed:'||i);        
      when others then 
        raise;
    end;
    i := i+1;
  EXIT WHEN i > length(p_str);
  END LOOP;

  -- second loop for building output
  i:=1;
  LOOP
    l_c := lower(substr(p_str, i, 1));   
    l_tc := substr(p_str, i, 1);
    begin
      l_nb_occurrences := l_dup(l_c);
        dbms_output.put_line(l_c||':xx:'||i||'||'||l_nb_occurrences);        
      if l_nb_occurrences = 1 then
        l_out_sngl := l_out_sngl || l_tc;
      else 
        l_out_dupl := l_out_dupl || l_tc;
      end if;

    exception 
      when no_data_found then
        dbms_output.put_line('why? there should be (see first loop).');        
      when others then 
        raise;
    end;
    i := i+1;
  EXIT WHEN i > length(p_str);
  END LOOP;

  return l_out_sngl || l_out_dupl;
exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
END f;
/
```

Which gives results:

```
select f('Array') from dual;
-- yArra
select f('Bubbles') from dual;
-- ulesBbb
```

Comment: I must put a stop on your fun coding becuase the result is not the same. When i execute `select f('Array') from dual` i get  `Aayrr` not  `yArra` which you showed. Same is the case for `Bubble`. It gives me `Bulesbb` not what your showed.

Comment: @XING, right, I forgot to fix the case-sensitiveness thing in my post... done

Comment: Even after it's not working. Check the master string to test. `select f('rajjjjkkmmaaljjjl') from dual;` Only working with `Bubble` and `Array` and even `Array` output should be `yrraA` or `yrrAa`. Order is not mentioned but certainly it cannot be `yArra`

Comment: I disagree. From OP example, output for `Array` should be `yArra`... Why do you change the order of the letters? Print non-repeating chars first, then we do what we want with the others.

Comment: becuase this is what OP posted under my answer below you comment under my answer. `No, We should not take that condition XING. OP should be uleBbb. if there are three b's/B's all of them should be considered as repeating characters ` . Hope now you agree.

Comment: I still think we could both be right... in our world at least.

Comment: Agreed since the OP requirement itself is not clear. +1 for your efforts

Answer (score -2):

Try this function...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION non_repeating_char_first (v_input IN varchar2)
   RETURN varchar2
IS
   str1 varchar2 (100);
   str2 varchar2 (100);   
   v_match    number;
   v_output   varchar2 (100);
BEGIN
   str1 := '';
   str2 := '';

   FOR i IN 1 .. LENGTH (v_input)
   LOOP

         SELECT   REGEXP_COUNT (v_input,
                                SUBSTR (v_input, i, 1),
                                1,
                                'i')
           INTO   v_match
           FROM   DUAL;

         IF v_match =1 THEN
           str1 :=str1||SUBSTR (v_input, i, 1);
         else
           str2 :=str2||SUBSTR (v_input, i, 1);             
         END IF;
   END LOOP;
   v_output:=str1||str2;
   RETURN v_output;
END;
```

Comment: This is not correct. The non-repeating character are not coming at the first. `select non_repeating_char_first ('rajjjjkkmmaaljjjl') from dual` When you execute this the non-repeating charactetr first come and then the repeating characters but the output is `rkkmmllaaajjjjjjj` which is wrong. Not sure how OP accepted this. Seems either OP question is wrong or your solutiin. This only works for `bubble` and i gues yesterday OP mentioned this as well

Comment: Hey XING.! I did came to know this just now as i was testing the code.

Comment: I modify the function little bit. I think this is the answer what you are looking for.

Comment: it works only for `Bubble` and `Array` same as @J. Chomel solution.